# What is a valid AWSPhone? What test values can be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html) say:

> The AWSPhone scalar type represents a valid Phone Number. Phone numbers are serialized and deserialized as Strings. Phone numbers provided may be whitespace delimited or hyphenated. The number can specify a country code at the beginning but this is not required.

What determines whether a given string is a valid `AWSPhone`? In addition, is there any safe way to generate (possibly a large number of) `AWSPhone` test values that are guaranteed to be valid but assuredly are not in-use phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at the popular google library for handling phone numbers

https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: Is this the library that AppSync uses to validate AWSPhone values? If not, then what relation does it have to the AWSPhone type?

Comment: Yes, this is the library

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? How do we know that this is what AppSync uses internally?

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: You cannot tell the exact rules how the type `AWSPhone` is validated in AppSync. However, if a value passes the test of the regular expression `/^\+?\d[\d\s-]+$/` or validation by [libphonenumber-js](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/libphonenumber-js/), then it is likely to be accepted by AppSync.

In the latest [AppSync Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html) (Oct 6, 2021 UTC), the description was updated to:

> A phone number. This value is stored as a string. Phone numbers can contain either spaces or hyphens to separate digit groups. Phone numbers without a country code are assumed to be US/North American numbers adhering to the [North American Numbering Plan (NANP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan).

This doesn't really tell exactly what AppSync expects. E.g. Must country code include `+` as prefix?

From AWS's public repositories on GitHub, there are hints:

- [amplify-js datastore util method](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/46ee5dd91c61f49bad4da8286b2f97c737d96631/packages/datastore/src/util.ts#L675-L677) for frontend validation:

  ```js
  export const isAWSPhone = (val: string): boolean => {
     return !!/^\+?\d[\d\s-]+$/.exec(val);
  };
  ```
- [amplify-appsync-simulator](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/08750a6f7f9e9326a81b5d45a7ef31bd9f30595f/packages/amplify-appsync-simulator/src/schema/appsync-scalars/index.ts#L3-L26) for amplify CLI mock features:

  ```js
  //...
  import { isValidNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js';
  //...
  const phoneValidator = (ast, options) => {
     //...
     let isValid = isValidNumber(value, country);
     //...
  }
  ```

Therefore, a value is likely to be accepted by AppSync if it passes the above regex test and validation by [libphonenumber-js](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/libphonenumber-js/) (or [libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber), assuming they work equivalently).

Answer (score 0):

libphonenumber-js finds both 5555551212 and 555-555-1212 as invalid. What I have read is area code 555 is not a valid area code. So it would be the ideal number to generate known invalid test phone numbers, as well as a perfect phone number area code to be a known invalid initializer. But alas, dynamodb declares it as invalid.